# Firebreath's example project FBTestPlugin not working in Mac 10.10

Tags: macos, npapi, firebreath

I had followed the Firebreath's official tutorial [Building on Mac OS X](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Building+on+Mac+OS+X) to build browser plugin in Mac 10.10 (Yosemite). But I couldn't able to install the generated plugin.

**Note:**

Tried copying the generated plugin to below directories,

`/Library/Internet\ Plugins/` and

`~/Library/Internet\ Plugins/`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a good stackoverflow question, it's more of a bug report... but I fixed this on a different branch awhile back, so I just cherry-picked it into master.  Try again, it should work.